# How to set MDI child form border to none?

Tags: forms, delphi, vcl, delphi-xe8

On my **MDI Form (Parent Form)**, whenever I trigger a command to create a new **MDI Child Form**, I do these stuff (but it doesn't work):

```
procedure TfrmMDI.CreateChildForm(const childName: string);
var Child: TfrmChild;
begin
    Child := TfrmChild.Create(Application);
    Child.Caption := childName;
    Child.BorderStyle := bsNone;
end;
```

I tried to set the **Border Style** of the **MDI Child Form** to *bsNone* through object inspector but it doesn't work as well.

I finally tried to set the **MDI Child's** Form BorderStyle through run-time however, it doesn't seemed to work too.

```
procedure TfrmChild.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    BorderStyle := bsNone;
end;
```

For additional information, my current **MDI Child Form** looks like this:

[image: Current Form]

We may want to set our **MDI Child's BS** like this **MDI Parent's BS**:

[image: Desired Form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is not how MDI is meant to be used.  The GUI you *want* to have would likely be better served by using client-aligned `TFrame` objects instead of MDI child forms.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, you made my day easy.

Answer (score -1):

Upon waiting for some answers, I have read a documentation from Embarcadero that states:

"*Changing the border style of an MDI child form to **bsDialog** or **bsNone** has **no effect***"

I tried to change the **Application Appearance** of my program to some pre-installed styles created by Embarcadero and It helped.

I just override the default style setting of my project.

[image: How to]

Finally, it looks like this. Any border style changes will be applied to your MDI Child Form if you override the default form style:

[image: Final]

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.BorderStyle

Comment: Your **workaround** is questionable. It may work today, but what if the style engine is fixed to deal **correctly** with MDI. I don't understand why you even use MDI when you destroy its main idea of having document windows that can be opened, moved, resized and closed. So, **why** are you using MDI to begin with? **What** do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: I admit that I didn't know about TFrames before. You have all the point, thanks.